# How to get all the contents of Hashtable and put into NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, hashtable, nsmutablearray

How to get all the contents of Hashtable[NSMutableDictionary] into NSMutableArray , which is to be done for iPhone application?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionary allValues]]
```

Comment: @Nefrubyr : How to print the values in the array.??
Is this the right procedure? ***NSLog(@"%@",array);

Comment: Yes, I think that should work.  Or `NSLog(@"%@", [array description]);` might format it a bit more nicely.